# How to programmatically center progress bar in layout?

Tags: java, android, listview, progress-bar, android-linearlayout

I want to programatically center my progress bars in code. Here is my code:

```
  LinearLayout streamLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            streamLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            streamLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            streamLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            LinearLayout newsLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            streamLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            streamLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            streamLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            mSwipeView.addView(streamLayout);
            mSwipeView.addView(newsLayout);
            mSwipeView.addView(new LinearLayout(this));

            ((LinearLayout) mSwipeView.getChildContainer().getChildAt(0)).addView(streamListView);
            ((LinearLayout) mSwipeView.getChildContainer().getChildAt(0)).addView(streamProgressBar);
            ((LinearLayout) mSwipeView.getChildContainer().getChildAt(1)).addView(newsListView);
            ((LinearLayout) mSwipeView.getChildContainer().getChildAt(1)).addView(newsProgressBar);
            ((LinearLayout) mSwipeView.getChildContainer().getChildAt(2)).addView(chartImageView);
```

How can I get the progress bar to be in the centered vertically, and horizontally in my layout?

Comment: In the center of what? Screen, layout?

Comment: i believe he is refering to the horizontal center in the layout.

Comment: yes, i am referring to the horizontal and vertical center of the layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using LinearLayout.layoutParams and setting them to the view. they contain a field gravity that you can set to Gravity.CENTER or similar.

[See This Link](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=312)

Comment: updated my code with references from your link. I can get it to show up centered horizontally, but I want it to be centered vertically as well. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you cant in a linearLayout. either you need to work with the weights or use a relative layout. when you center gravity in a linear layout it just centers horizontally. the workaround is to make the wrapper linear layout be larger than the wrapped view and make the view's gravity center.

Comment: You can also try this things in an Xml tester layout before adding them programatically. or even making the xml layout and just inflating with a layout inflater which seems kinda the easier way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
View.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);// or fitCenter
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Will this actually work on the progress bar?  Or is it just for images?